# 389 LDAP server: woes setting it up

Tags: linux, ldap, fedora-20

I'd like to use a LDAP server as a centralized rolodex

I'm on fedora 20

I'm following the 389 administration manual, but when I get to create a root object, I get this window from the visual console

[image: screenshot of the error]

When running `setup-ds-admin.pl` I was asked about a Directory Manager and went with the proposed default and then I tried again with `uid=user,dc=blah,dc=net,cn=Directory Manager` but got the same result.

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That error is quite self-explanatory. You need to log in to the visual console using the Directory Manager credentials you provided during setup-ds-admin.pl execution (default "cn=Directory Manager") instead of whatever credentials you are using right now.

In case you don't remember your Directory Manager password you can reset it following [this guide](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Howto:ResetDirMgrPassword)

Comment: thanks. The error is not self explanatory at all. In fact "cn=directory manager" is the user name for the directory manager, while "my-user123" is the user name for the administration user. So in the first case it seems to be a distinguished name or part of it, in the second it's a plain vanilla user name. With no advise whatsoever anywhere. I spent hours doing stupid tries